# aggregating in a particular order

Tags: postgresql

I have a table which has columns `period`, `value`, and `entity` representing a set of different timeseries. I want to select `entity`, `array_agg(value)` to get the time series for each entity. However, to get the order in the array_agg correct the items need to be aggregated in order of `period`. I don't care what order the final output is in, as long as each array is in the right order. How can I go about this? My first pass was to use an `order by period` statement, but that refers to the final output rather than the order of aggregation, and errors out anyway because `period` is not in the group by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually pretty clearly answered in the documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES). The correct syntax is `array_agg(value ORDER BY period)`.